# MySQL query works, but not from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query im trying to run from php with the mysql_query() function, it is as follows

```
    $result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT score,name,time,
    FIND_IN_SET( score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC,time ASC ) FROM Highscores )) AS rank 
    FROM Highscores WHERE name = $name Order BY rank LIMIT 1");
```

This does not return any result for some reason, while the same query in phpMyAdmin returns the top ranked high score.

I just don't get it.. anyone got any ideas?

Regards
/Fred

Comment: did you also add a fetch statement to your code like mysql_fetch_assoc etc. ?

Comment: Did you properly connect to the database?

Comment: $name needs to be sanitized and placed in single quotes

Comment: Are you checking `mysql_error()` to see what the actual error is? I expect it's probably because you need to add quotes around the string `name=$name`

Comment: Your underlying problem is `WHERE name = $name`. This should be `WHERE name = '$name'`, but please look into using PDO instead of PHP's `mysql` library, which will be removed in the near future.

Comment: I have had similar problems with this as well.  I believe I ended up creating stored procedures and calling those instead.  Calling stored procs is usually a better way to do this anyway imo.

Comment: shouldn't it be `WHERE name = ". $name. " Order`

Comment: @Ed Gibbs. I'm not sure "which will be removed in the near future" is accurate. It will most likely hang around for quite some time.

Comment: You're right - I was trying to add some urgency but I overstated my case.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable should be enclosed in {} since it is in a string. Also because name seems like it should be user generated make sure that you are escaping the string before putting it into a query. Other people are also right, because name is presumably a string it needs a set of quotes around it as well.

Answer (score 0):

please try this and let us know if there is an error so we can debug it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT score,name,time, FIND_IN_SET( score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score 
ORDER BY score DESC,time ASC ) FROM Highscores )) AS rank FROM Highscores WHERE name = $name Order BY rank LIMIT 1") or die("error is: ".mysql_error());
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Couldn't you at least fix the quote problem?

Answer (score 0):

give a try with this :-

```
$qry="SELECT score,name,time,
    FIND_IN_SET( score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC,time ASC ) FROM Highscores )) AS rank 
    FROM Highscores WHERE name ='".$name."' Order BY rank LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with `WHERE name = $name`, should of course be`WHERE name = '$name'` as pointed out in comments

Comment: also worth mentioning (I know a lil' old but worth raising for people like me who come across this) that name is a mysql keyword and should be wrapped in ``